# Why aren't defaults, setters, validators and middleware not applied for findOneAndModify mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

While reading [Mongoose's documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), I found the following note for `findOneAndModify`:

> Although values are cast to their appropriate types when using the
>   findAndModify helpers, the following are not applied:
>
> ```
> defaults
> setters
> validators
> middleware
> ```

The documentation goes on to explain that, in order to get these, one should follow the `traditional` approach, which uses `findOne` and `save`.

My question: why aren't these functions applied? I understand that this can be simply a design decision of the Mongoose developers, but, looking at the code for `findOne` and `findOneAndUpdate`, I don't see much difference.

**Note:** This is not necessarily specific to `findOneAndUpdate`, but applies to other methods like `findOneAndRemove`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` allows you to make raw call to `MongoDB` with `Mongoose`. It just sends an [`findAndModify` request to `MongoDB`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

`setters`, `validators` and `middlewares` requires `Mongoose` to fetch all the data first.

`findOneAndUpdate` is faster then the traditional way, because it simply makes a single call to `MongoDB` skipping all the `Mongoose` magic.

The only actual difference between `Mongoose` `findOneAndUpdate` function and raw `db.collection.findAndModify` operation is that `Mongoose` casts your update operation according to your schema.

**Update.** [According to API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) it `issues a mongodb findAndModify update command`.

When you're using traditional way with `findOne` and `save`, `Mongoose` fetches all the data and wraps it into [Mongoose document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js). Then it catches all your update operations applying your getters. Then, when you call `save` on the document, it runs all validators and hooks and issues an atomic update operation on modified fields. It's not replace the old document with the new one like [raw `MongoDB` `db.collection.save`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) do.

Comment: Can you please provide some reference?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny this answer is no longer 100% correct. you can call `findAndUpdate` with the option `runValidators`.